# Access the device clock alarm settings?

Tags: android, android-intent

My app needs to wake the user up in the night so I would like to access the device's clock alarm and add my own in there. The alarm times shifts throughout the month, so I would need to access it and update it.

For example, I would like to add a daily alarm in the device clock alarm. Then everyday, I would like to run some calculation and adjust the time for the daily alarm.

Is this possible? I found `AlarmManager` but this seems like a scheduler not the device clock alarm. Perhaps there is an intent for the clock alarm? The screenshot below is the setting I am trying to access from my app (without rooting the device).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a tutorial about programming alarms for Android.

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

The thing is that is not needed to access the native clock app to set them, you can do it with your own app.

Be aware that this will not program an "Alarm"(with music and so on), it will only provide you the possibility to shcedule some task. In your case this task could be wake up the user with a loud music or whatever.

Comment: Thx for clearing up my misconception of needing to use the native clock alarm!

Comment: Hope I've been useful :)